# Flutter change duration of countdown timer

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdown

I am using the package `circular_countdown_timer`  and `GetX`where I want to create a timer where the user can change its duration before it starts. Then the user should be able to reset it and choose a new duration.

Declaration of the timer widget (relevant parameters shown):

```dart
Obx(() => CircularCountDownTimer(
  duration: pc.workTime.value.inSeconds,
  controller: pc.timerController,
  isReverse: true,
  autoStart: false
))),
```

where `pc` is a `GetXController` that has an observable `workTime` variable which contains a `Duration`. This `Duration` is changed and set to a new value every time the minutes are changed as so:

```
NumberPicker(
    value: pc.workTime.value.inMinutes,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
    onChanged: (value) {
      pc.workTime.value = Duration(minutes: value); //updating the observable
    }),
```

[image]

---

## Results & Errors

Example: Initial time 25min changing to 35min

1. If the duration of 25min is changed, the actual text on the timer changes to 35min.
2. However, if start is clicked, the timer somehow forgets the new value and starts to countdown from 25min.

**Theory**

```
CountDownController timerController =  CountDownController(); //declared in the GetXController 'pc'
```

I believe that this controller is not updating dynamically like the widget is. the widget gets the new value because of Obx but the controller doesn't update. **How can I update the controller or change the duration correctly?**

THANK YOU!

Comment: The word GetX discouraged me from reading to the end.